# Definition of a closable operator

Tags: functional-analysis, hilbert-spaces, operator-algebras, unbounded-operators

Given an unbounded densely defined operator $D: {\frak dom}(D) \subseteq \mathbb{H} \to \mathbb{H}$, on some Hilbert space $\mathbb{H}$, it graph is the subspace 
$$
\mathcal{G}(D) := \{(x,D(x)) \text{ such that } x \in {\frak dom}(D)\}.
$$
We say that an operator is **closed** if $\mathcal{G}(D)$ is a closed subspace of $\mathbb{H \oplus H}$.

My question is asking of the definition of closure for $D$. We could say, $D$ is **closable** if

A) the closure of $\mathcal{G}(D)$ in $\mathbb{H \oplus H}$ is the graph of some operator

OR

B) there exists a closed operator $\widetilde{D}$ such that $\mathcal{G}(D) \subseteq \mathcal{G}(\widetilde{D})$.

Clearly, if $D$ is closable in the sense of A then it is cloasble in the sense of B. Is the opposite inference true? If not what is an instructive example?

Comment: I'd start by looking for an example of some $D$ that has several closed extensions $D', D''$ that are incompatible, or that has a sequence $D_1,D_2,\ldots$ of closed operators such that $\mathcal{G}(D_i)\subset \mathcal{G}(D_{i+1})$ but $\cup_i\mathcal{G}(D_i)$ is not the graph of anything.

Comment: Your notation of B) is unclear. What does $\widetilde{D}$ mean? what is $D'$? what is the relation between them?

Comment: @uniquesolution: sorry that was a typo, it's fixed

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Condition $(B)$ is equivalent to condition $(A)$. In this answer I show that $(B) \implies (A)$ since you know how to do the other direction.

The key point is that a closed subspace $\mathcal{G} \subset H \oplus H$ is the graph of a closed extension of $A$ if and only if $\mathcal{G}(A) \subset \mathcal{G}$ and $\mathcal{G}$ has the single valued property
$$(x,y_1),(x,y_2) \in \mathcal{G} \implies y_1 = y_2$$ 
which is equivalent to $$(0,y) \in \mathcal{G} \implies y = 0$$
since $\mathcal{G}$ is a linear space. In general, $K \subset H \oplus H$ is the graph of an operator if and only if it is a linear subspace with the single valued property.

So we want to check that if $(B)$ holds then $\overline{\mathcal{G}(A)}$ has the single valued property. But this is easy since if $(0,y) \in \overline{\mathcal{G}(A)}$ then $(0,y) \in \mathcal{G}(\tilde{D})$ since  $\mathcal{G}(\tilde{D})$ is a closed subset containing $\mathcal{G}(A)$. Since $\mathcal{G}(\tilde{D})$ is the graph of an operator, it has the single valued property and so $y = 0$. Hence $\overline{G(A)}$ has the single valued property and so is the graph of an operator.

Comment: Hey Rhys this is an old question, nonetheless, I was wondering why we say that the graph belongs to the direct sum of the Hilbert spaces rather than the cartesian product?

Comment: @RScrlli This should just be purely notational; the two notions should coincide in this case. In general the direct sum is a bit more a natural object for taking the sum/product of infinitely many spaces which I guess might be the reason for seeing this notation more often but it makes no difference here.